# What is the shortcut to get data if the value of a parameter is null?

Tags: c#

I am trying this but it gives me and error:

```
App.availableCards = App.availableCards ?? App.DB.GetAllPhrasesCount();
```

Both App.availableCards and the return from App.DB.GetAllPhrasesCount() are ints.

What I need to do is to set the value of App.available cards if it is null and this is done by setting it to the value of App.DB.GetAllPhrasesCount();

It says ?? cannot be applied to operators of type 'int' and 'int'

Can someone advise what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should show us the data types involved. Which of these can be null ?, Your error messages suggest the types are not nullable.  If App.availableCards is an int, it can never be null. If App.DB.GetAllPhrasesCount() returns an int, it can never be null. (It can be 0 though, which is a very different thing than null)

Comment: There's a difference between `null` and `0`.  `int` can not be `null`, but it can have the value `0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
App.availableCards = App.availableCards == 0 ? App.DB.GetAllPhrasesCount() : App.availableCards ;
```

`int` is not a reference type, and therefore not nullable.

Comment: Woah ! First answer with this line code, but you lack `:` in it

Comment: everyone else lacked : also :-)

Comment: Revision commented, as you were.

Comment: Wasn't me either :-)   I will accept your answer as it's the first with the ":"   :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need this

```
App.availableCards =App.availableCards == 0 ? App.DB.GetAllPhrasesCount() : App.availableCards ;
```

Comment: Woah ! Second answer with the exact same line code, and you still lack `:` in it

Answer (score 1):

`App.availableCards` needs to be a nullable int (int?) to use the null-coalescing operator.

You need to use something like this if you are using an int;

```
App.availableCards = App.availableCards == 0 ? App.DB.GetAllPhrasesCount() : App.availableCards;
```

For more information, see here [?? Operator (C# Reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)

Comment: Woah ! Third answer with the exact same line code, and you all lack `:` in it

Answer (score 0):

because int is not nullable.

```
        //This failes
        int x;
         x = x ?? 10;

       // this works
        int? Y = null;
         Y = Y ?? 10;
```